# Powershell pscustomobject with array properties to Csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I got an `$Object` with a ton of properties which look like this:

```
IsSynchronized   : { False, False }
```

What I want is to do something like :

```
$Object | Export-Csv C:\Test\Merge.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

To get a CSV containing :

```
IsSynchronized
--------------
False
False
```

But as expected I get

```
IsSynchronized
---------------
System.Object[]
```

Is there a good way to get a ton of the object's properties in a `.CSV` ?

I have 6 `.csv` files with values and I try to add them in to one big `.csv` for further processing.

---

Edit:
I asked about this Topic yesterday but i need to make more clear what i want.

I create a PSCustomObject and fill it with Arrays:

```
$Object = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject

$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "CPUHost"  -value $global:CPUHost
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "NumCpu"   -value $global:NumCpu
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "MemoryMB"  -value $global:MemoryMB
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "CPU Usage (Average), Mhz"  -value  $global:CPUUsageAverageMhz
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "CPU Usage (Average), %"  -value  $global:CPUUsageAverage
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Memory Usage (Average), %"  -value $global:MemoryUsageAverage
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Network Usage (Average), KBps"  -value  $global:NetworkUsageAverageKBps
$Object | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Disk Usage (Average), KBps"  -value  $global:DiskUsageAverageKBps
...
```

All of these Global Variables are Arrays because i never know how many Values i get in the first place.
They are filled by lopping through 6 CSV Files i will allways get.

After running this bit i will have a Object looking like this:

```
CPUHost                        : {xxxx}
NumCpu                         : {20}
MemoryMB                       : {36094}
CPU Usage (Average), Mhz       : {3914,33}
CPU Usage (Average), %         : {8,91}
Memory Usage (Average), %      : {70,17}
Network Usage (Average), KBps  : {439,68}
Disk Usage (Average), KBps     : {1994,93}
...
```

What i want is to Export that in to a CSV Displayed like :

```
CPUHost NumCPU MemoryMb CPUUsage  ...
------- ------ -------- ---------
xxxx     20      36094    3914      
                          33
```

With every Value in its own Cell.

What i get is instead of the values : System.Type.[] which is technically correct but not what i need.

I allready tryed to `-join`  the values but that will leave me with the values in the same cell

Comment: How do you merge the 6 CSVs into one?

Comment: Thats what i ask ^^"

Comment: Basically - or how to make my way work

Comment: @BjörnTrier You seem to be mixing _presentation_ and _storage_ formats - if you store the data like you suggest in a CSV file and someone sorts the rows, your data will be meaningless. Who is the intended audience for the stacked view?

Comment: Well i need it in a csv file at the end of the day

Comment: There are unlimited ways to make one CSV from multiple others. The worst would be to copy paste the content into one txt and change the ending to `.csv` but it would be a CSV in the end of the day... The question is, what do you want to do with it and how is it going to be processed? Excel, Database import, Powershell Script etc.

Comment: I will use that CSV for a VBA Macro which gets the Values by the Colum Names and fills them in to a Table inside a Word File.

Comment: Are all CSVs having the same headers or different ones? Do you want  a complete new row if one property contains multiple values or do you want them in a single cell (or maybe even both for different columns)? Your last code snippet is harder to create and probably not very usefull since you will have a lot of empty rows with just one filled cell.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you have one object with multiple properties like what was posted. I assume you have an object that looks like the following:

```
IsSynchronized Property2 Property3
-------------- --------- ---------
{False, False} {1, 2, 3} {string1, string2, string3, string4}
```

You could do the following:

```
$loopmax = $object[0].psobject.properties |% {($_.Value | measure-object).Count} | Sort -desc | Select -First 1
$newobject = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $loopmax; $i++) {
    $hash = [ordered]@{}
    foreach ($p in $object[0].psobject.properties.name) {
        $hash[$p] = $object.$p[$i]
    }
    [pscustomobject]$hash
}
$newobject | convertto-csv -notype
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem wise to do.  CSV isn't very good for representing or storing rich or hierarchical objects.  The problem is even worse when the property is an object, in your case it's a flat array.  You can output as you suggest / request, and other answers have demonstrated:

```
IsSynchronized
--------------
False
False
```

However, this disrupts the property's relationship to the other properties. If you have other types like `[String]` & `[Int]`, or even varying numbers of elements in array typed properties things are going to get weird quickly!

If you must stick with CSV you can sub-delimit the field.  A great example of this is Exchange Message Tracking logs.  They are CSV files delimited on the typical ",", but the recipients field is sub-delimited on a ";".

An example in code might look something like this:

```
$Object = 
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Prop1 = "one"
    Prop2 = "two"
    Arr1  = @( 1,2,3,4 )
}

$Object | 
Select-Object Prop1, Prop2,
    @{ Name = 'Arr1'; Expression = {$_.Arr1 -join "," } } |
ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";"
```

Results:

```
"Prop1";"Prop2";"Arr1"
"one";"two";"1,2,3,4"
```

> Note: To use full fidelity data in a later process would require appropriate handling on input.  However, if you follow other solutions and said weirdness occurs you'll be left with a similar issue; having to handle on the input side everywhere you intend to use that data.

Given CSV's shortcomings JSON may be a better choice to store & reuse full fidelity objects. `Export/Import CliXML` are interesting for this.

Comment: The thing is in a later step i have VBA Macro in a Word File which i programmed to read CSV Data and Fill Tables within the Wordfile with the Data. But the Conditions changed, they want a Second Function to do the same with diffrent Data which they give me in 6 CSV Files which i now try to merge in to one. Due to the fact that the Values are not allways the same lenght like there can be 1-6 lines i cant place them underneath eatch other because in the VBA Macro i grab certaint Colums and say take the header as sepreate factor and the values as array to later fill them in with these information

Comment: I think of creating a empty CSV and i allready got every value in a array. I think i could give them a static name and add the values dynamic through looping all csv files and writing there propertys as arrays in variables

Comment: Exporting it as XML still has no Values just : System.Object[]

Comment: I didn't test the `Export-CliXML command, but if it's anything like `ConvertTo-Json` you  may need to play with the `-Depth` parameter.  That said, it sounds like you'll need to rewrite the VBA/Word side regardless...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the literal question asked (although I'm not sure that's what the OP actually wants)...

If you have a single object with a property that contains an array of values, you can expand them out into a new array and then convert *that* to csv as follows:

```bsh
$obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
    "IsSynchronized" = @( $false, $false )
}

$obj
# IsSynchronized
# --------------
# {False, False}

$data = $obj.IsSynchronized | foreach-object {
    new-object pscustomobject -Property @{ "IsSynchronized" = $_ }
}

$csv = $data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$csv
# "IsSynchronized"
# "False"
# "False"
```